# Django how to show available item only in CBV List view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two models,  `Car` and `Booking`. A `Car` is a `ForeignKey` field in `Booking` model. If `Car` is booked, it's still showing in the `Car` list.

I have `is_available_car` model field in `Car` model set to `default=True`. If `Car` is booked, it will not show until it's unbooked. I have a booking form and if `Car` is booked, user cannot book it and it doesn't shown in the `CarListView`

Help me please. Thank you.

**models.py**

```
class Booking(models.Model):

    booking_name = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=False)
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_customers' )
    book_car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_car')
    booking_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    booking_end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    rental_price = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    times_pick = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.booking_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("buggy_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
class BookingView(FormView):
    template_name = 'buggy_app/booking.html'
    form_class = BookingForm
    model = Booking 
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # kwargs['car'] is the car booking now!
        try:
            kwargs['car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('car', ''))
        except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
            kwargs['car'] = None
            return super(BookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(BookingView, self).get_initial()
        if 'car' in self.request.GET:
            try:
                initial['book_car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET['car'])
            except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
                pass
                return initial

class CarListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'cars'
    model = Car

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(CarListView, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(is_available_car=True)
        return qs
```

Comment: please check your indent. it's really hard to see

Comment: you want to only filter `Car.objects.filter(is_available_car=True)`?

Comment: i want to show only available car only after booked . in list view i had show if car is avaiable show it. after car booked is_available_car have to be false .

Comment: Views.py  https://pastebin.com/D8AqcvcH

Comment: Models  https://pastebin.com/YTsARhHh

Comment: Then the problem is your car object not changed to  `is_available_car=False` stauts after booked?

Comment: weird. It should be work. there's any error?

Comment: yes its not changing i want  that car to be false if its booked

Comment: it stills show in listview of car . you can see i use query if car is not booked it shows in list. mean is car available it show to the list if is booked it doesnt have to show in  CAR listview

Comment: your booking form works well? I mean your Booking obect created well?

Comment: my booking work welll. and i seen from django admin also but want to override that availablity part

Comment: I can't see `car.save()` in your code above. Is it in your real formview?

Comment: i am not saving the car . just booking car using foreignkey of car in it .

Comment: Oh then when your car object update for `is_availbale_car=False`?

Comment: i want that car to be false if its booked ? how can i do this

Comment: https://pastebin.com/D8AqcvcH this one isn't your view? this view already has the code...

Comment: yes its my view i updated it but in the cars which is booked are still showing in the car list view

Comment: can you check that your car is booked in django shell? After make booking, just check the car object is updated well

Comment: wait i see 2 min

Comment: @seuling yeah you are right . its not booked in admin its not showing booking. but in carlistview car is not showing that i booked . but the form is not saving i think so . in admin i cannot see any booking

Comment: @seuling how to save  the form its not saving the form just hiding car from carlistview

Comment: what do you mean not saving form and just hiding car?

Comment: I submit the booking form . after that in carlistview the car i select not show in carlistview  its booked but after that in my admin i see there is no booking

Comment: @seuling its working now . but after deleting from the admin the booking of car. that car is not showing in listview

Comment: how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i find the solution by the help of @seuling**

```
   class BookingView(FormView):
        template_name = 'buggy_app/booking.html'
        form_class = BookingForm
        models = Booking
        def form_valid(self, form):
          car_id = self.request.GET.get('car', '')
          car = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
          car.is_available_car = False
          car.save()
          form.save()
          return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)
          success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          # kwargs['car'] is the car booking now!
                  try:

                       kwargs['car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('car', ''))
                 except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):

                       kwargs['car'] = None
                 return super(BookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: @seuling thanks / yeah it was solved. by i am getting a new problem . after submiting a form i want to show in pop up what the user booked . you can say i detail of that booking .